# jsonschema $ref - jsonschema.exceptions._WrappedReferencingError: Unresolvable

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a problem with the jsonschema $ref.

I have a directory schema/04 with multiple json files.

Assume the main file A:

```
(...)
    "memoryMode": {
      "title": "attribute",
      "description": "description of attribute",
      "$ref": "attributes.json#/$defs/attributes"
    },
(...)
```

and file b (attributes.json)

```
(...)
{
  "$id": "https://company-url/spec/04/attributes.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Attributes",
  "description": "Subschema describing attributes.",
  "$defs": {
    "attributes": {
      "title": "attributes",
      "enum": ["attribute_one", "attribute_two"]
    }
  }
}
(...)
```

I get:

jsonschema.exceptions._WrappedReferencingError: Unresolvable: attributes.json#/$defs/attributes

What am I doing wrong? A colleague is using the same thing and it apparently works fine. So I assume it has to be an issue with my local setup (I run it in a fastapi docker container). I appreciate any help on how to find and resolve the issue!

Comment: Generally, JSON Schema libraries need you to load the schemas you intend to reference into the library somehow. How that's done depends on the library you're using. I can't help further, but hopefully that helps nudge you in the right direction.